# Having Issue on Redirecting With Session in WordPress

Tags: php, redirect, headers, session

I am trying to create a simple login system in WordPress using core PHP but I am getting this error message

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at
> /www/www/www/wp-content/themes/mytheme/header.php:20)
> in
> /www/www/www/wp-content/themes/mytheme/page-solutions.php
> on line 9

In the `header.php` template I have

```
<?php
session_start();
/**
 * The header.
 *
 */
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
```

and in the `page-solutions.php` page

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Solutions
 *
 */
get_header();

if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
header("location: home");
exit;
}
```

As you can see I am trying to redirect not logged users to `front-page.php` which I called it Home but I am getting error on `header("location: home");` Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`header` can't be used once the headers have been sent, the moment you output anything such as a tag, or even a blank space, PHP will send out the headers telling the browser to expect a HTML document.

In order to send a HTTP header to redirect, you need to do it *before* this happens. This means you cannot do this after `get_header()` is called, you have to do it before that call, and before any other HTML output. Generally, this is not something that works well inside templates.

Other notes:

- you should be using the WordPress function to do this `wp_safe_redirect`
- if you're redirecting to the homepage you shouldn't be using `home`, pass `/home` to go to `example.com/home` or use `home_url()` instead to retrieve the URL of the homepage
- PHP sessions will not work on many WordPress hosts, and there are major security issues that require special handling. They're also incompatible with many caching systems. You also can't use it to bypass cookie legislation as PHP sessions use a cookie to identify which session belongs to the visitor. So use cookie based logins instead.
- You should use the built in user management instead of reinventing it

Comment: Thanks a lost for perfect comment Tom, So by using the `built in user management` can I give access of viewing the front pages? I do not want users have access to admin panel but able to see secured front pages?

Comment: that's possible but would be a separate independent question. If this answer answers your question consider marking it as the correct answer using the check button underneath the voting arrows